# Write TypeScript declaration file for callable module

Tags: typescript, type-declaration, cldr

The `cldr-data` package is defined something like:

```
function cldrData(path) {
  // ...
}

cldrData.all = function() {
  // ...
}

cldrData.entireMainFor = function(locale/*, ...*/) {
  // ...
}

cldrData.entireSupplemental = function() {
  // ...
}

module.exports = cldrData;
```

How should I write a type declaration file for such a package?

Comment: Can't you define a class with `all`, `entireMainFor` and `entireSupplemental` as methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
declare module 'cldr-data' {
    interface CldrData {
        (path: any, ...args: any[]): any;
        availableLocales: any;
        all(): any;
        entireMainFor(locale: any, ...args: any[]): any;
        entireSupplemental(): any;
    }

    declare const cldrData: CldrData;
    export = cldrData;
};
```

Usage:

```
import cldrData from 'cldr-data';

cldrData('main/en/numbers');
cldrData.entireSupplemental();
cldrData.entireMainFor('en');
console.log(cldrData.all());
```

Comment: Does this work? I tried importing with `import cldrData, { all } from 'cldr-data';` and I have a runtime error.

Comment: If it works for you, I think it would be a good idea to edit your answer with the usage and the good import statement.

Comment: You're right, there's a problem here. I'm trying some fixes out.